# ADB Command to display time format in HH:MM:SS.SSSS

Tags: android, bash, shell, youtube, adb

I am working on QoE analysis of youtube by finding different states(state buffering, state playing etc..) using ADB commands. The following command shows the status of the youtube video playback.

```
adb shell dumpsys media_session | grep "state=PlaybackState"
```

But the problem with above command is it gives output log without timestamp. But I need timestamp for data analysis. Then I found a solution to print time along with state status.

```
printf '[%s] %s\n' "$(date '+%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')" "$line";
```

Combination of both commands result output like this:

```
state=PlaybackState {state=7, position=-1, buffered position=0, speed=1.0, updated=533687, actions=0, custom actions=[], active item id=-1, error=Bluetooth audio disconnected}
      state=PlaybackState {state=0, position=0, buffered position=0, speed=1.0, updated=1243174, actions=8192, custom actions=[], active item id=-1, error=null}
[2021-06-24 15:38:48]
```

But my requirment is to print the time along with milliseconds(15:38:48.078 like that). How can I do it?

Comment: Please, for your next posts, have a look at the [help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting) and learn how to properly format your code and error messages.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [date](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/date.1.html) man-page, you need to use `%N` formatter to get nanoseconds.
 Since you need milliseconds, you could round the nanoseconds with `%3N`.
Final printf command should be:

```
printf '[%s] %s\n' "$(date '+"%Y-%m-%d %T.%3N"')" "$line";
```

Comment: Could you please accept my answer? I am hungry for some reps nowadays. Thanks!